# one fixed div to push down another fixed div with both at top:0

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i have a toolbar that has a more button. When clicked a large panel is bought down with jquery. Only problem is both the toolbar and the large panel must be fixed to the top. Therefore the panel does not push down the toolbar when opened. When clicked the panel should be at the top, above the toolbar and the toolbar should be pushed down. Both should stick at the top of the page when scrolled so position:fixed is needed.

Here is a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FAgpk/).

Comment: Do you want toolbar to be sticked to the top or pushed? Because you change your mind twice in the description..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By animating the top of the membersbar along with the slideDown of the submenu. Like so:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertjan/FAgpk/5/)

```
$('#more').toggle(function() {
    //show its submenu
    $('.large').slideDown(500);
    $('.membersbar').animate({ top: '+=150' }, 500);
}, function() {
    //hide its submenu
    $('.large').slideUp(500);
    $('.membersbar').animate({ top: '-=150' }, 500);
});​
```

Comment: Maybe he wants the more-button to slide along? :)

Comment: yeah I know hehe Like this :P

Comment: Beautiful, thanks very much. I only started learning jquery yesterday so don't really have any idea